# architecture error when accessing database using Golang

Tags: macos, go, mysql-connector

I was using Golang and trying to connect MySQL through the following codes, which were also the tutorial codes shown on [go-database\sql](http://go-database-sql.org/accessing.html). However, I got some errors reporting some of the files were not built for architecture x86_64 and and some symbols were not found for architecture x86_64.
All the codes were editing in Goland(2019.3.4) on macOS 10.15.4 platform.

```
package main

import (
    "database/sql"
    _ "github.com/go-sql-driver/mysql"
    "log"
)

func main() {
    db, err := sql.Open("mysql", "root:mmmm572011@tcp(127.0.0.1:3306)/bookstore")
    if err != nil {
        log.Fatal(err)
    }
    defer db.Close()
}
```

Here is what I got:

```
GOROOT=/usr/local/Cellar/go/1.14/libexec #gosetup
GOPATH=/Users/michaeltan/go #gosetup
/usr/local/Cellar/go/1.14/libexec/bin/go build -o /private/var/folders/tr/c6mwrj1928949n_6pnpj3mk40000gn/T/___go_build_main_go /Users/michaeltan/GolandProjects/test_sql/main.go #gosetup
# runtime/cgo
ld: warning: ignoring file /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/MacOSX.platform/Developer/SDKs/MacOSX.sdk/usr/lib/libpthread.tbd, file was built for unsupported file format ( 0x2D 0x2D 0x2D 0x20 0x21 0x74 0x61 0x70 0x69 0x2D 0x74 0x62 0x64 0x2D 0x76 0x33 ) which is not the architecture being linked (x86_64): /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/MacOSX.platform/Developer/SDKs/MacOSX.sdk/usr/lib/libpthread.tbd
ld: warning: ignoring file /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/MacOSX.platform/Developer/SDKs/MacOSX.sdk/usr/lib/libSystem.tbd, file was built for unsupported file format ( 0x2D 0x2D 0x2D 0x20 0x21 0x74 0x61 0x70 0x69 0x2D 0x74 0x62 0x64 0x2D 0x76 0x33 ) which is not the architecture being linked (x86_64): /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/MacOSX.platform/Developer/SDKs/MacOSX.sdk/usr/lib/libSystem.tbd
Undefined symbols for architecture x86_64:
  "___stack_chk_fail", referenced from:
      _x_cgo_init in _x004.o
      __cgo_sys_thread_start in _x004.o
  "___stack_chk_guard", referenced from:
      _x_cgo_init in _x004.o
      __cgo_sys_thread_start in _x004.o
  "___stderrp", referenced from:
      __cgo_sys_thread_start in _x004.o
      _x_cgo_sys_thread_create in _x005.o
      _x_cgo_thread_start in _x008.o
  "_abort", referenced from:
      __cgo_sys_thread_start in _x004.o
      _x_cgo_sys_thread_create in _x005.o
      _x_cgo_thread_start in _x008.o
  "_fprintf", referenced from:
      __cgo_sys_thread_start in _x004.o
      _x_cgo_sys_thread_create in _x005.o
  "_free", referenced from:
      _threadentry in _x004.o
  "_fwrite", referenced from:
      _x_cgo_thread_start in _x008.o
  "_malloc", referenced from:
      _x_cgo_thread_start in _x008.o
  "_nanosleep", referenced from:
      _x_cgo_sys_thread_create in _x005.o
      __cgo_try_pthread_create in _x005.o
  "_pthread_attr_destroy", referenced from:
      _x_cgo_init in _x004.o
  "_pthread_attr_getstacksize", referenced from:
      _x_cgo_init in _x004.o
      __cgo_sys_thread_start in _x004.o
  "_pthread_attr_init", referenced from:
      _x_cgo_init in _x004.o
      __cgo_sys_thread_start in _x004.o
  "_pthread_cond_broadcast", referenced from:
      _x_cgo_notify_runtime_init_done in _x005.o
  "_pthread_cond_wait", referenced from:
      __cgo_wait_runtime_init_done in _x005.o
  "_pthread_create", referenced from:
      _x_cgo_sys_thread_create in _x005.o
      __cgo_try_pthread_create in _x005.o
     (maybe you meant: __cgo_try_pthread_create)
  "_pthread_detach", referenced from:
      _x_cgo_sys_thread_create in _x005.o
      __cgo_try_pthread_create in _x005.o
  "_pthread_mutex_lock", referenced from:
      __cgo_wait_runtime_init_done in _x005.o
      _x_cgo_notify_runtime_init_done in _x005.o
      _x_cgo_set_context_function in _x005.o
      __cgo_get_context_function in _x005.o
  "_pthread_mutex_unlock", referenced from:
      __cgo_wait_runtime_init_done in _x005.o
      _x_cgo_notify_runtime_init_done in _x005.o
      _x_cgo_set_context_function in _x005.o
      __cgo_get_context_function in _x005.o
  "_pthread_sigmask", referenced from:
      __cgo_sys_thread_start in _x004.o
  "_setenv", referenced from:
      _x_cgo_setenv in _x006.o
     (maybe you meant: _x_cgo_setenv)
  "_strerror", referenced from:
      __cgo_sys_thread_start in _x004.o
      _x_cgo_sys_thread_create in _x005.o
  "_unsetenv", referenced from:
      _x_cgo_unsetenv in _x006.o
     (maybe you meant: _x_cgo_unsetenv)
ld: symbol(s) not found for architecture x86_64
clang-4.0: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)

Compilation finished with exit code 2
```

Additional information:
Golang(1.14 Darwin/amd64) is installed through Homebrew.
Mysql is installed through Homebrew, and database in the codes has created before in the terminal commands.

Answer (score 0):

Do you really need to install Go via Brew? I don't trust this installation. I prefer using the official installation to avoid problems.
https://dl.google.com/go/go1.14.1.darwin-amd64.pkg

Answer (score 0):

I have resolved the problem after reviewing this [issue](https://github.com/flutter/flutter/issues/43713) on GitHub. All you have to do is make the Conda environment setup comments in your .zshrc or .bash_profile.